# Paypal API - how to set payment page type

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

using express checkout, I want to select if the user will be redirected to paypal login page, or the page where to insert the credit card data and optionally register an account.

I looked at advance variables https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

but i do not found how to customize the default payment page type,

- pay with my paypal account (LOGIN)
- or credit card payment without registration

anyone can help me plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LANDINGPAGE` field in the `setExpressCheckout` call to specify the default user interface, either `Login` for account login payments, or `Billing` for credit card form page.

*Be noted that this field will not always work since the checkout layout has been redesigned, you may try with the redirection URL in this format to display the selected page:*

**Login checkout page (by default):**
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-XXXXXXXXXX

**Credit card form page:**
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/xoonboarding?token=EC-XXXXXXXXXX

*`token`=EC Token returned by `setExpressCheckout` call

[image]